# Setup Google AdWords Conversion Tracking in Google Tag Manager for Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.2.1

I am new to Magento (Community Edition) and need to setup the AdWords Conversion Tracking in Google Tag Manager. Is there an manual for it? The Google Tag Manager is installed already with MagePal Google Tag Manager and working.

I have already checked the documentation on http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/google-tag-manager-create-tag.html but it seems to be very old.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** login to your tag manager account

**Step 2:** create a new tag by clicking on the ‘New Tag’ tab.

**Step 3:** Enter the name of the tag as ‘Adwords Conversion Tracking’.

**Step 4:** Click on Tag Configuration and select the tag type as ‘Adwords Conversion Tracking’.

**Step 5:** Copy the conversion ID and conversion Label and Paste those values in the appropriate fields in Adwords tag configuration. Conversion Value, Order Id and Currency code can be set up using the data layers build by either third party module or Magento.

**Step 6:** Click on the advanced settings and select the tag firing option as once per page.

**Step 7:** Click on the ‘Triggering’ tab and create a new trigger to fire this tag on specific page i.e. checkout/success page. Enter a unique name for the trigger. Select the trigger type as ‘Page View’, and choose the trigger to fire on some pages where page path contains 'success' or 'checkout/success'

**Step 8:** Save the tag.

If out of the box Magento doesn't give you the data layers for Order ID, Conversion Value and Currency code then you can use the following extension -:

https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-google-tag-manager-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking.html